# Connection refused FTP python 2.7

Tags: python

I am using the ftplib module and want to connect to FTP on my localhost. I am using the following code example:

```
import ftplib
f = ftplib.FTP()
f.connect("localhost")
f.login()

ls=[]
f.retrlines('MLSD',ls.append)
for entry in ls:
    print entry
```

It gives me a `socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused`

How do i connect to my localhost and what am i doing wrong? Eventually i would want to send files from a client code to server code using ftplib, both running on the same machine. This is for a project, i know in reality you wouldn't have both on the same machine.

Comment: First, please report complete tracebacks, or at the very least which line has the error, instead of just the error message.

Comment: Second, do you have an FTP server running on your local machine? If not, obviously you can't connect to a server that doesn't exist.

Comment: If you don't have one running, your OS may come with one (I believe IIS/PWS on many Windows versions includes FTP), or may have a standard way to get one (e.g., on most linux distros, there are plenty to choose from available via apt/rpm/etc.), or you can just search for one to install manually.

Comment: Finally, if you're trying to use `ftplib` to build a server: As the description of [the library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) "FTP protocol client" makes pretty clear, you can't do that. There _are_ third-party FTP server libraries for Python, and it's not that hard to write from scratch, but if you just want to do the standard "serve files out of a directory without any kind of remapping" thing, it's much easier to just use a pre-built server than to build one yourself.

Comment: It was my ftp localhost that was messed up. I fixed it now! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the socket.error exception occurs on line 3, where you have `connect()`.

`Connection refused` indicates that the operating system or the firewall rejected the connection.  The most likely reason is that you don't actually have an FTP server running on your local machine.

You didn't say whether you do or you don't, and you didn't say what operating system you're using.  But by default, operating systems don't come with an FTP server installed and running.  So you need to install a [compatible FTP server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_software).  A good one to consider is [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) Server.